# Disabling Windows Update and Defender as Installation Options

Tags: windows-installation, windows-to-go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1rj.png)

In rufus the following options are able to be used to streamline the installation.  I am wondering if it is possible to disable Update and Defender within the installation (prior to first use) as this causes a lot of wasted time for me.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-ntlite-guide/

Answer (score 0):

For standard Windows (not some non-Microsoft product), no.

When you install Windows it will update.

Unless you install a good 3rd party AV, then Windows Defender will also be installed.

You need a Corporate Version to get around this.

You will save a lot of time by doing the install normally and let it update overnight. Your system will run a whole lot better as a result.

My Windows Systems run 7x24 and do not cause any issue at all.

Comment: I have windows 10 enterprise, how do i customize the installation options to deploy onto a USB drive as unofficial "windows-to-go" so that these services are disabled by default?  I have to manually disable them for a particular use case of mine and it causes a lot of wasted time each fresh installation.

Comment: If your Enterprise system is part of a company, ask Company support. Otherwise I do not think you can avoid installing updates or WD.  Allow to update overnight and then change your Anti Virus next day.